# Show that $T = cL$ for some real number $c.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $L$ and $T$ be two linear transformations from a real vector space $V$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $L(v) = 0$ implies $T (v) = 0.$ Show that $T = cL$ for some real number $c.$

**I have taken hours to come up with the idea. So I want you to verify the logic:**

Without loss of generality suppose $L\ne0.$ Consequently $L(V)$ is of dimension $1.$

$\exists~\alpha\in V$ such that $L(\alpha)\ne0.$ Then $L(V)=\langle L(\alpha)\rangle.$ Let $c=\dfrac{T(\alpha)}{L(\alpha)}.$

Choose $v\in V.$ Then $L(v)=dL(\alpha)$ for some $d\in\mathbb R\\\implies L(v-d\alpha)=0\\\implies T(v-d\alpha)=0\\\implies T(v)=dT(\alpha)\\\implies T(v)=cdL(\alpha)\\\implies T(v)=cL(v)\\\implies T=cL$

Comment: The beginning already's problematic: $\;L\neq 0\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\implies T\neq0\;$ . You're only given $$\;Lv=0\implies Tv=0\iff \ker L\subset \ker T\;$$ But for this, which is easily mendable, the rest looks fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I've updated my post.

Comment: Nicely done, @sujan.

Answer (score 1):

*Community wiki answer to remove the question from the Unanswered queue:*

Now your proof looks fine.